# Get next and previous records in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

how to get next and previous records using `buttons` instead of `href`,

for example

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    //Question and options will come here,
    //when click on next button next question should appear and 
    // if I click on prev button it should goto prev question
    <button type ="submit">Next Question
    <button type ="submit">Previous Question
</form>
```

my Controller

```
$questions = Question::find($qId);
$options = Question::find($qId)->options;
$previous = Question::where('id', '<', $questions->id)->max('id');
$next = Question::where('id', '>', $questions->id)->min('id');
return view('Pages/User/Questions/Question2')
        ->with('options',$options)
        ->with('questions',$questions)
        ->with('previous',Question::find($previous))
        ->with('next',Question::find($next));
```

Now How to send next and prev `id` on the button submit.

Comment: You want to send current question id with form ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam yes

Comment: Just use hidden input field whats the problem ?

Comment: @Sagar yes I can do that but the problem with getting next and prev record on button submit.

Comment: I've added answer take a moment to view it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

You need to add value to button and on submit value will be submitted as well. So, You can get desired record.

```
 <form method="post" action="/">

     // your question content

     <input name="qId" value="{{$question_id}}" hidden>

     <button type ="submit" name="option" value="0">Previous </button>
     <button type ="submit" name="option" value="1">Next </button>

 </form>
```

Now, You have to check which button is clicked by using option value,

```
public function getQuestion(Request $request){

    if($request->option==0){

         // Get previous record using $request->qId

    }else{

          // Get Next record using $request->qId

   }

  // Write code here to return data
}
```

Hope you understand,

Comment: Is there any other way to do??

Comment: I've similar case before, and solved with this, other people might give you best solution. best of luck